# Flex: easy way to see if a line has any content?

Tags: lex

Among many rules in my Altair BASIC Flex file is this one:

```
[\n]
{
    ++num_lines;
    ++num_statements;
    return '\n';
}
```

`++statements;` is not actually correct - in theory the line might be empty (due to bad data in the .BAS file for instance) and thus not have any statements on that line. So is there any way to know if there's any tokens in front of the \n since the last \n? I know you can do this with the BEGIN() et all, but that seems like a LOT of work for a simple problem! Is there an easier way?

Comment: Do you really need to keep track of the number of statements? And if you do need it, can't you count it in the parser (which can more easily tell whether a line contains a statement or not) instead of the lexer?

Comment: My application has no parser, just a lex. The goal is to count the number of statements in total compared to the number of lines.

Comment: > *So is there any way to know if there's any tokens in front of the \n since the last \n?*  Well, yes; the parser above the lexer would know this! The logic that recognizes statements should increment `num_statements`. The logic that recognizes line endings should increment `num_lines`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to match a blank line, although I'm not sure that's really what you're looking for.

The first pattern matches a line which only contains space and tab characters (adjust as necessary to match other whitespace). The second pattern matches the same whitespace when it's not at the beginning of a line. (Actually, it would match the whitespace anywhere, but at the beginning of a line, the first pattern wins.)

```
^[ \t]*\n ;
[ \t]*\n  { ++num_statements; return '\n'; }
```

Instead of counting lines yourself, I suggest you use `%option yylineno` so flex will count them for you. (In `yylineno`.)

Comment: Ok, I think I see this... the first one will fire if the entire line is WS, but the second one will only fire if the whitespace is after... yes I think that is what I need. I'll put the first one right at the top of the .l so that they get snapped up early.

Comment: @maury: flex matches all rules in parallel. Asvlong ad you put rules which might match the same token in the right order (specific first, then fallback), it really doesn't matter how close to the beginning a rule is

Comment: @maury: the second rule could have just been `\n`, as in your question; presumably you have some other rule which ignores whitespace. I did it explicitly to demonstrate the parallel (and it's slightly more efficient).